# BI stack: Mondrian, Pivot4J and d3.js

Tags: d3.js, business-intelligence, mondrian

I want to create a BI web application, that allows users to set parameters (date ranges, departments, persons, ...) for predefined views (revenue for a year/month/day, sales figures for a shop, ...) and gets a beatiful representation (UI) of the data generated.

I am new to this (BI) field and spent some hours digging into the stack and this is what I thought of: 
I assumed that I would have to start with setting up an OLAP server (like **Mondrian**) on my relational database and define schemas on it. I then want to execute predefined queries on the cube (via **Pivot4j**?) and put the data into a table/chart/view/... on my webpage, I found the **d3.js** stuff beautiful.

Well, that's a lot of new technology for me. Does the stack I thought about even make sense? Is it possible? Do I even need Pivot4J in that case?

I am a bit overwhelmed right now and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

See the Pentaho Business Analytics server. It features Mondrian, Olap4j plugs on top of it to display cube analysis and the CDE/CDF dashboard plugins allow you to plug D3 in a dashboard and build a visualisation. I built a D3 based dashboard a while ago. Although very basic in terms of visualisation, it may be of interest to you to check how to integrate D3 and CDF/CDE.

demo.ubiquis.co.uk:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:public:ubiquis:world_population:world_population.wcdf/generatedContent

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume Mondrian and Olap4J are used to transform the MDX queries to normal SQL queries? And what exactly is the CDE/CDF dashboard plugin you were talking about to "plug to D3"? Are that plugins that transform the output to a readable format for d3? I still dont grasp the concept of Pivot4J and what it could do in my stack. Do you have an idea about that aswell?

Comment: Correct on Mondrian. Olap4j picks up users requests and converts them into MDX queries which are passed to Mondrian. CDF: community dashboard framework, a javascript framework integrated with Pentaho to provide access to data; CDE: community dashboard editor, an editor that creates the HTML and JS for you. There's also CDA: community data access, that manages queries and cache. As for D3: you can add new JS files to any dashboard (a jquery plugin, for example), and CDE will add it to the list of includes.